# Why do I only get one option when flagging a question?

Tags: support, flagging

This [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/293695/22) doesn't seem to actually answer the question, so I went to flag it as "Not an answer" <sup>*</sup>.

The dialog box that pops up gives me precisely one option:
[image]

Why do I only get that one option for flagging.

<sup>*</sup> **NOTE**: This question is *NOT* about whether that is an answer or not, it's only about the flagging options presented.

**NOTE 2:** That answer is now deleted. Maybe I hit it in a transitory state where I'd loaded the page prior to the final delete vote (so it appeared to still be there), but by the time I went to flag it, it had been deleted.

Comment: I think your second note is a self answer. That's the popup when the answer is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You saw only one option because the post had been deleted by the time you tried to raise a flag. At that point, there's not much that can be done to the post -- the only thing I can think of is editing -- that doesn't need moderator abilities.

Comment: Basically my note 2. That made more sense when I went back to get the question link, but it was utterly confusing at first glance.